# import header files into c++ using cmake 3.10

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project structured as such

```
-project
-CMakeList.txt
--bin
--cmake
--lib
---models
----object1
-----object1.h
-----object1.cpp
----object2
-----object2.h
-----object2.cpp
----...
--src
---main.cpp
---CMakeList.txt
```

I am trying to import and use objects from the models folder in the main.cpp file using cmake 3.10.

How should I configure my cmake files, and where should they be placed to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is there a directory for `object1` and `object2`? Are these separate libraries?

Comment: The short answer is that you will need to update the include path with `target_include_directories` on the target, or just `include_directories`, and then `#include` the header in C++ from the specified path as you normally would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Put a CMakeLists.txt in `lib/models`:

```
add_library(models STATIC
  object1/object1.cpp
  object2/object2.cpp
)
target_include_directories(models PUBLIC object1 object2)
```

and in your main CMakeLists.txt, `target_link_libraries(main models)`

The PUBLIC include directories will be propagated to the main target.

Comment: in ```target_link_libraries(main models)``` is main the main project? defined as ```project(main) ?```

Comment: The main *target*, that you created with add_executable.